# Tizen standalone-wearable-app with internet access

Tags: tizen-web-app

Is it possible to connect to the internet from a tizen-standalone-app on a wearable through the bluetooth connection?

Currently the internet access works with wifi but not with bluetooth. Are there settings for this or do we have to write an application for the phone too for accessing the internet?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to connect to the internet through a standalone app using bluetooth.

**How to achieve this?**

You need to change the setting in the **Gear Manager**. There is a setting avaiable within the gear manager where you need to switch on the option for sharing internet via bluetooth with the Gear, then your web app will be able to use the internet.

Click on the **Settings** option available under **General** Section. [Check attached image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Thats good news for me. Unfortunately the standalone app was not possible to connect to the internet even with the 'shared internet connection' turned on. Do we have to integrate some privileges in our standalone-app besides the normal `internet`?

Comment: Nope. You don't have to include any privilege other than internet.

Comment: Thanks, this is invaluable information. You cannot find much information on the internet if you just happen to miss the gear manager settings. My application is rejected by samsung just because it shows an error message when it cannot reach internet. It is just nonsense to me. An application should be able to require internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
You need to check you phone and allow 'Blouetooth tethering' in Access Point Settings.

Tested on Gear S3 connected over bluetooth to my Nexus 5x (WiFi off)